# After updating (2015-11-22) of LaTeXTools in Sublime Text 3, the traditional builder fails to work

Tags: sublime-text

As saying in the question's title, when I build my tex file, only a blank build_panel shows up without any messages.

The "traditional" builder is used in setting-user, while after replacing it with "simple", it works regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the indentation in `Packages/LaTeXTools/builders/traditionalBuilder.py`:

- Access the file mentioned above with `Preferences > Browse Packages ...`
- Navigate to `LaTeXTools/builders` and open `traditionalBuilder.py`
- At lines 132-133, change with appropriate indentation:

  ```
  for i, c in enumerate(cmd):
       cmd[i] = c.replace("%E", engine)
  ```

Comment: what do you mean by "appropriate indentation" ? Do we need to put it forward or backward? And how much? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The answer given by neok worked for Sublime Text 2. Basically, the line cmd[i] = c.replace("%E", engine) is indented using spaces instead of tabs. Remove the spaces and put tabs and it should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is now fixed with this [Emergency fix release](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/commit/350a2c78a7e8b61b2f5aefa260b22dac80a044ac)